# Is tzinfo=tzutc() same as +00:00 in python?

Tags: python

Are both the time formats equivalent in python :

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 7, 46, 0, 609263, tzinfo=tzutc())

datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 17, 7, 46, 0, 609263, +00:00)
```

Also is there a way to replace `tzinfo=tzutc()` with `+00:00` and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the [source of dateutil](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dateutil/dateutil/trunk/view/head:/dateutil/tz.py)

```
ZERO = datetime.timedelta(0) # same as 00:00

class tzutc(datetime.tzinfo):

    def utcoffset(self, dt): 
        return ZERO

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO
```

which I assume you are using.

You'll see that according to the `datetime` object you put `tzutc` into the two are equivalent because `tzutc` will return the following:

```
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

But the class also includes a whole range of functions that you may find useful at some point if you wish to use them.

You can replace them easily enough by just using a variable and using that variable in every place you would use either `00:00` or `tzutc`.